# SQL users' upvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, up-votes, sql

I am not trying to be rude, *at all*, but I just have a quick question. Maybe some stats can back me up, but this is my personal feeling.

*Why do SQL users upvote less than others?*

I answer a variance of tags and find that questions regarding SQL get a lot of views but very few votes. Is this just me or am I missing something? [This is an example of a Q today, 1 vote 75 Views at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973786/building-sql-query/1974347#1974347). Just let me know if I am incorrect.

Comment: Uppercase keywords scare people away before they can even think about voting? ;-)

Comment: I see at least here voting happens... X-)

Answer (score 10):

A lot of developers use SQL and so have a passing interest in it (the bike shed effect) which causes SQL questions to get a lot of views.

But SQL is actually very complex and has a lot of variation depending on the RDBMS vendor. Since a lot of SQL questions are specific to a particular RDBMS and since most users don't label their RDBMS correctly you get a lot of people who view the question, read it and realize it's talking about a feature of an RDBMS they know nothing about, so they leave.

That'd be my guess, anyway.

Comment: Not enough apostrophes.

Comment: As for complex: maybe people are reluctant to vote while they cannot easily be totally sure an answer is correct?

Comment: @Arjan: Yeah, that's what I'm sayin' here. People show up thinking, "Oh it's just a query" and then realize that it's a horribly RDBMS-specific problem involving proprietary keywords and then leave because they can't evaluate answers properly.

Comment: You must be sure before you vote? Oops...

Comment: No, you don't. Actually you vote on the helpfulness of an answer. This means you can upvote totally wrong answers if you think they are helpful.

Comment: Of course it's not a rule, but I like to be (reasonably) sure. Especially if I happen to read an answer quite soon after a question has been asked, as first answers seem to get more upvotes than later answers anyway, while future later answers might in fact prove earlier answers wrong. (So far, I don't recall seeing a helpful answer that I knew was *totally* wrong.)

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: Me neither. :)

Answer (score 7):

Top 200 tags ordered by avg score on answers excluding community wiki and closed answers.

If you want the reputations go answer questions like: "What is the best perl cpan module for controlling vim, is there any way to integrate it with git?"

Sqls state is not spectacular, but its also not as dire as say questions about flex or wcf.

#### TagName                 AvgView AvgScore Total

```
perl                    364     3.48     11610  
syntax                  431     3.09     3469   
stl                     469     2.89     3896   
subjective              604     2.77     42850  
vim                     372     2.64     3711   
git                     431     2.63     4982   
compiler                407     2.62     4630   
c                       432     2.58     34463  
beginner                361     2.54     15863  
string                  589     2.50     8845   
list                    363     2.49     3582   
language-agnostic       460     2.49     13757  
python                  367     2.47     45977  
gcc                     410     2.46     2756   
math                    511     2.45     6063   
emacs                   340     2.45     2955   
c++                     425     2.44     74710  
delphi                  398     2.40     10148  
best-practices          401     2.37     33357  
learning                455     2.33     8072   
programming             420     2.31     13076  
string-manipulation     544     2.31     3419   
generics                428     2.29     5988   
memory-management       420     2.28     3428   
collections             491     2.25     3258   
optimization            443     2.25     7640   
templates               323     2.24     2989   
oop                     345     2.23     7296   
version-control         467     2.22     8135   
array                   445     2.19     4539   
arrays                  498     2.18     6065   
algorithm               467     2.16     14920  
cocoa                   330     2.13     7400   
inheritance             339     2.12     4102   
class                   353     2.08     3796   
books                   365     2.05     5454   
object-oriented-design  309     2.05     4501   
unix                    424     2.04     5461   
performance             421     2.04     14241  
exception               392     2.04     6045   
bash                    508     2.01     5253   
homework                369     2.01     7809   
datetime                550     2.01     4511   
open-source             385     2.01     5122   
command-line            656     2.00     3721   
memory                  454     2.00     4591   
not-programming-related 420     1.98     7007   
data-structures         453     1.98     4129   
objective-c             350     1.97     14269  
unicode                 463     1.96     2810   
encryption              404     1.95     3023   
reflection              374     1.95     4212   
shell                   479     1.94     3684   
documentation           291     1.94     3700   
ruby                    299     1.93     17047  
svn                     451     1.93     11587  
regex                   352     1.91     16992  
linux                   450     1.90     16467  
design-patterns         328     1.90     7394   
design                  294     1.90     10858  
powershell              364     1.89     2086   
ide                     515     1.88     5241   
files                   462     1.87     3052   
unit-testing            316     1.87     10467  
multithreading          390     1.86     11176  
security                317     1.81     10390  
django                  264     1.81     8741   
c#                      397     1.81     160632 
web-development         347     1.81     16944  
parsing                 428     1.78     4004   
.net                    379     1.76     85645  
architecture            284     1.76     4908   
google                  338     1.76     2218   
java                    413     1.76     90942  
library                 367     1.75     4507   
linq                    343     1.74     10128  
tools                   447     1.74     5738   
osx                     434     1.72     4544   
mac                     434     1.71     4687   
debugging               333     1.68     6812   
qt                      302     1.66     2881   
file                    392     1.66     3802   
gui                     397     1.63     6722   
url                     373     1.63     3279   
testing                 310     1.63     5586   
.net-3.5                478     1.62     3689   
database-design         280     1.60     7079   
cocoa-touch             511     1.59     7407   
http                    392     1.58     5079   
graphics                391     1.57     2835   
windows                 433     1.57     22285  
html                    406     1.56     32917  
database                360     1.55     21745  
xcode                   350     1.55     3379   
logging                 364     1.55     3346   
winapi                  381     1.54     6248   
api                     302     1.54     4054   
javascript              428     1.54     59089  
web                     317     1.53     5325   
google-app-engine       280     1.52     2353   
php5                    249     1.51     2444   
mvc                     344     1.50     5604   
visual-c++              332     1.49     3516   
sql                     372     1.49     45709  
php                     280     1.49     66751  
browser                 390     1.48     3132   
opengl                  375     1.47     2433   
css                     425     1.47     24625  
sqlite                  367     1.46     2838   
visual-studio           348     1.46     16485  
maven-2                 342     1.45     2066   
tsql                    449     1.45     8759   
vb.net                  373     1.45     14752  
rest                    341     1.43     2493   
email                   330     1.43     4244   
vb6                     367     1.43     3000   
oracle                  502     1.43     9410   
search                  316     1.43     3589   
web-applications        294     1.43     4505   
ruby-on-rails           243     1.42     17666  
activerecord            230     1.42     1706   
.net-2.0                495     1.42     2630   
dll                     385     1.41     3000   
serialization           388     1.41     3001   
stored-procedures       494     1.41     4078   
validation              383     1.41     4053   
json                    409     1.41     4089   
images                  483     1.40     2503   
error                   371     1.39     3591   
asp.net-mvc             298     1.38     18688  
mfc                     294     1.37     2317   
linq-to-sql             303     1.36     6299   
postgresql              324     1.36     3071   
dom                     456     1.36     3157   
jquery                  423     1.36     35449  
networking              385     1.35     3360   
sockets                 363     1.35     2860   
iphone                  360     1.35     25412  
mysql                   273     1.34     28013  
sql-server              417     1.33     34176  
events                  378     1.32     3815   
xml                     339     1.31     15331  
xslt                    305     1.31     3064   
authentication          360     1.28     3258   
deployment              329     1.28     3452   
tfs                     275     1.27     1926   
configuration           388     1.27     2805   
forms                   337     1.27     3053   
windows-vista           519     1.27     2229   
eclipse                 453     1.26     7203   
iphone-sdk              366     1.26     7516   
android                 303     1.26     2880   
swing                   351     1.25     3668   
query                   308     1.25     4656   
visual-studio-2008      335     1.25     11176  
winforms                366     1.24     13331  
visual-studio-2005      407     1.22     2982   
sql-server-2005         381     1.21     9878   
spring                  400     1.21     2995   
table                   450     1.21     2454   
firefox                 402     1.20     3912   
com                     249     1.19     2637   
server                  220     1.18     2259   
wpf                     368     1.18     14826  
sql-server-2008         289     1.17     2923   
internet-explorer       468     1.17     5550   
apache                  299     1.17     5054   
asp.net                 349     1.16     62945  
xaml                    356     1.16     2808   
ajax                    366     1.15     11645  
entity-framework        297     1.15     2834   
silverlight             304     1.14     6133   
ado.net                 331     1.14     2592   
vba                     495     1.13     3470   
zend-framework          282     1.13     2522   
msbuild                 314     1.13     1727   
session                 363     1.12     2850   
image                   377     1.12     3281   
nhibernate              295     1.10     4759   
actionscript            410     1.09     2130   
ms-access               392     1.05     5340   
web-services            373     1.04     8351   
jsp                     371     1.04     2775   
databinding             437     1.03     3115   
windows-mobile          309     1.02     2069   
iis                     358     1.02     4628   
hibernate               433     1.01     3789   
tomcat                  426     0.99     2361   
soap                    353     0.98     1639   
flash                   333     0.98     7536   
excel                   536     0.98     5909   
sharepoint              366     0.97     6982   
actionscript-3          391     0.97     5803   
mod-rewrite             189     0.97     1875   
pdf                     387     0.96     3206   
wcf                     329     0.95     6862   
flex                    391     0.90     7365   
asp.net-ajax            488     0.83     1700   
reporting-services      442     0.81     1560   
gridview                530     0.66     2072
```

SQL

```
select top 200 TagId, AVG(ViewCount) as AvgView 
into #tags
from Tags t
join PostTags pt on pt.TagId = t.Id 
join Posts p on p.Id = pt.PostId
where p.CommunityOwnedDate is null and p.ClosedDate is null
group by TagId 
order by count(*) desc 


select TagName, AvgView, cast(Avg(p.Score + 0.0) as numeric(4,2)) as AvgScore, count(*) as Total 
into #t
from Posts p
join Posts q on q.id = p.ParentId
join PostTags pt on q.Id = pt.PostId
join Tags t on t.Id = pt.TagId    
join #tags tt on tt.TagId = t.Id
where p.CommunityOwnedDate is null and p.ClosedDate is null
group by TagName, AvgView 
order by Avg(p.Score + 0.0) desc


exec spShog9
```

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/why-is-subjective-the-top-upvoted-tag-for-questions

Comment: Interesting... SQL beats out jQuery *and* VB6...

Comment: Could you pull the sames stats, but including the AVG view Count per question included with the Avg Votes?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that Java is so far down the list. I would have thought it was in the top 10 or so. Maybe it's because common languages attract a lot of answerers who really don't know what they're doing; a *good* Java answer might attract more upvotes than a good Vim answer, but there are more bad answers to drag the average down.

Comment: I was surprise math was so high but then I had a look through the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502021/how-do-i-round-a-decimal-to-a-specific-fraction-in-c lots of math questions are trivial and trivial clear cut questions attract answers that get lots of votes

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I admit I've wondered about the same thing.  IME, the total votes would be ~10% of the views.  Also depends on:

- competency: Could be too esoteric for someone to be comfortable voting for an answer
- timing & amount of traffic: All my 10+ voted answers were made during day time in North America

It's partly why I hesitate to answer data modeling questions these days - the user typically doesn't understand the answer, SO isn't the place to explain it, and there's even less people who will agree or vote for an answer.